# For loop doesn't print last substring

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make a program which replaces a series of ascii codes to a string. Example input:

```
strin1 = "65 66 67 68 69"
```

But every time I run the program the result of the last ascii number is not produced. It just displays (note the missing 69):

```
65
66
67
68
```

This is my code:

```
cyfry = str(raw_input("put numbers here: "))
str = ""
length1 =  len(cyfry)

for a in range(0,length1,1):
   if (cyfry[a] != " "):
      str += cyfry[a]
   else:
      print str
      str = ""
```

Why is not the last substring not printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only prints something when it arrives at a space. As your input does not *end* in a space, it does not print what `str` contains when you reach the end of the input.

A simple solution is to add `print str` at the very end of your program (outside of the loop).

Note that you can use `cyfry.split(" ")` to get the "words" into a list. And then you can use `int()` to convert such a word into an integer. `chr()` can be used to get the character for that numerical code. Finally, you can join those individual characters to a new string with `''.join()`:

```
cyfry = raw_input("put numbers here: ")

str = ''.join([chr(int(ch)) for ch in cyfry.split(" ")])
print str
```